# How to center pasted picture in excel chart with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have my code below that takes in a range and converts it to a picture that I automatically save.  The picture always is pasted in the top right.  Is there a way to center the picture on the chart or even shrink the chart to fit only the picture size?

```
Sub topicture(Sendrng As range)

        Dim xcht As Chart
        Dim Sname As String
        Sname = ActiveSheet.Name
        Sendrng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
        Set xcht = Charts.Add
        With xcht
            .ChartArea.ClearContents
            .Paste
            .ChartArea.Left = (xcht.ChartArea.Width - .Width) / 2
            .Export Filename:="CDrive\Photos\" & Sname & ".jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
            .Delete
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize the chart if you put it on a worksheet:

```
Sub tester()
    ExportRangePicture Range("B4:G20"), "C:\_Stuff\test1.jpg"
    ExportRangePicture Range("B4:G4"), "C:\_Stuff\test2.jpg"
End Sub


Sub ExportRangePicture(Sendrng As Range, fPath As String)
    Dim xcht
    Sendrng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    Set xcht = Sendrng.Parent.Shapes.AddChart
    With xcht.Chart
        Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 0
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop
        .Parent.Width = Sendrng.Width
        .Parent.Height = Sendrng.Height
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:=fPath, Filtername:="JPG"
        .Parent.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```